# ReactJS, change string to number inside a component

Tags: reactjs

I have this component that the idea is must return a value as Number, it receives a string:

```
// <InputNumber>
import React from 'react';
import NumberFormat, { NumberFormatProps } from 'react-number-format';

export type InputNumberProps = NumberFormatProps;

const InputNumber: React.FC<InputNumberProps> = ({ onChange, ...rest }) => {
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(event);
    }
  };

  return (
    <NumberFormat {...rest} onChange={handleChange} />
  );
};
```

With this code I'm not doing nothing with the value that receives. Currently I have another component called `Main` that is using `InputNumber` like this way:

```
// <Main>
import React from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';

import InputNumber from '../components/InputNumber';

const Main: React.FC = () => {
  const onChange = (val: any) => Number(val.target.value);

  return (
    <Container>
      <InputNumber onChange={onChange} />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

So with the props `onChange` I'm actually changing the `string` that receives from `IntegerNumber` and it returns a `number` which is the whole idea.

So, my question is, how can I do that change on the values from string to number but not outside `IntegerNumber` through the props `onChange`? I just want to use `InputNumber` and convert there the string tha receives and returns numbers, always.

Comment: `onChange(Number(event.target.value))` ?

Comment: Inside `handleChange`? I can't, because: `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeEvent '`

Comment: `onChange = (val: any) => parseInt(val.target.value);` tried this?

Comment: Number of parseInt works but I don't want to convert from string to integer/number outside the component `IntegerNumber`. The code that put works, what I need is to do the convertion inside `InputNumber`